# Static Sitemap with weekly updates for Dynamic Website

Tags: seo, sitemap

I have a dynamic website in which products, news and other stuff are added on daily basis. Since, I read everywhere having a sitemap can only help but not hurt the site, I decided to create one for myself using an online sitemap generator website and uploaded it to the root of my website. Currently i have 5000 URLS which should increase over time i guess.

My question is can I follow the procedure of weekly generating and updating the sitemap file at server for search engines or should i do it daily?

What's your opinion in this regard, a static generated sitemap for a dynamic website? Also having a sitemap won't stop google bots from crawling the website daily?

Let me know your opinions as to whether to go forward with this or drop the sitemap altogether

Answer (score 1):

It's a good practice to update the sitemap every time your site receives a new page. This can be easily done automatically in PHP, Google supports up to 50,000 urls within one site map and then your need to split into multiples with a limit of 50,000 each.

If your finding the process is slowing down the server then its time to upgrade hosting or change the method of which your using to generate the sitemap, for example sitemaps should be appended every time a new page is added rather than re-making the sitemap as a whole.

Comment: I can do that but will need to append the xml file whenever any content is added. My site is in asp.net mvc 3 so not sure if php scripts can be used

Comment: ASP.net will have a php equivalent way of doing it.

Comment: removed the sitemap. Seemed to have a negative impact. URL index came down

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternative method which is to use a RSS feed where you would push your new post/articles/Urls when they are ready. You would need to submit your RSS feed to [PubSubHubBub](https://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com/publish). Google would come and visit it frequently to check whether you have published updated or new content.

> My question is can I follow the procedure of weekly generating and updating the sitemap file at server for search engines or should i do it daily?

It depends how fast you want your content to be crawled and indexed. You decide. By updating your sitemap daily, bots are more likely to visit your new pages sooner.

> Also having a sitemap won't stop google bots from crawling the website daily?

Not at all.